# polynomial satisfying condition

Tags: polynomials

I found a question in an exam asking for the sum of coefficients in terms of $n$ of the quotient of division of $f=ax^{n+2}+bx^n+2$ to $(x-1)^2$ given that $(x-1)^2 \mid f$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Writing $f=ax^{n+2}+bx^{n}+2=(x-1)^2\cdot g(x)$, where $g(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots+a_1x+a_0$ and comparing coefficients would yield $a_0=2$ and then that would mean the coefficient of $x$ on RHS is not null leaving the only posibility for $n$ to be $1$. In other words, I found out that the only polynomial $f$ satisfying the hypothesis is $f=x^3-3x+2=(x-1)^2(x+2)$. However, the answer they provide is $n^2+2n$ which made me think I'm wrong, but I can't see where.

Comment: You have $a_1$ with $x$ along with $-2xa_0$ so their sum may indeed be zero.

Answer (score 1):

$1$ is a double root of $f (x) $

which means that

$f (1)=0$  and  $f'(1)=0$

this gives

$$a+b+2=0$$

and

$$f'(1)=a (n+2)+nb=0$$

thus

$2a-2n=0$ or $n=a $.

you can finish it.